# 2 headers lined up with 2 images side by side

Tags: html

I have the following HTML structure currently:

```
 <div id="image" style="margin: 20px;">
        <h5>
          <span>DriverName1</span>
          <span>DriverName2</span>
        </h5>
        <img src=/>
        <img src= />
    </div>
```

I am trying to make the images appear side by side which they are doing, but the headers for drivername1 and drivername2 are appearing right next to each other over the same image. How do I make these spans match up with the top left edge of each image? I tried adding separate headers over each image but that makes the images go vertically one on top of the other then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can consider using display:flex for this

check the following snippet

```css
div{
  display:flex;
 }
.image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:1px solid;
  margin-left:10px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image" style="margin: 20px;">
  <section class="image">
    <header>DriverName1</header>
    <img src="http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/BMW-2-series.jpg">
  </section>
  <section class="image">
    <header>DriverName2</header>
    <img src="http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/BMW-2-series.jpg" width=25px height=25px>
  </section>
</div>
```

Non-flex solution

```css
div * {
  display: inline-block;
}
.image {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
}
header {}
```

```html
<div id="image" style="margin: 20px;">
  <section class="image">
    <header>DriverName1</header>
    <img src="http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/BMW-2-series.jpg">
  </section>
  <section class="image">
    <header>DriverName2</header>
    <img src="http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/BMW-2-series.jpg" width=25px height=25px>
  </section>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for something a little more supported than flex, but this is a good solution, and works well in newer environments.

Comment: Added non-flex solution ..please check if this is what you want

Comment: did this help at all...please add your solution if it did not help,it will be a learning for us too

Comment: It did, this got me to where I needed to go, thanks!